# vue-socket.io не работает совместно с socket.io: ошибка cors

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, vue-cli

Текст самой ошибки:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NTV30Xu' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.[image: Список ошибок]

Прописанные подключения на клиенте:
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
debug: true,
connection: 'http://localhost:3000',
vuex: {
store,
actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
}
}))

Три вида попытки прописывания cors на сервере по ссылке:
https://gist.github.com/Fiasko99/4fff36a2403023f4d9eb7406629c093a

Comment: скорее всего ты ставишь cors не в том приложении. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38749535/4496422

Comment: ставил все там, просто версия socket.io была крайне нерабочей к данному случаю)

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы нашлось простым откатом версии socket.io для сервера на 2.3.0(2.2.0 тоже рабочая, дальше не перебирал, возможно есть ещё)
Можно использовать даже простые cors() для express, это никак не помешает работе сервера

Answer (score 0):

Как я решил проблему/код на сервере

```
        const app = require("express")();
        const server = require("http").createServer(app);
        const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
           allowEIO3: true,  
           cors:{ origin: true, credentials: true, },
        });
```